# ctrl+c not killing backgrounded function

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I created this script:

```
code fn()
{
  sleep 1001
}

fn &
sleep 1000
echo "finish"
```

When I  runt it and list processes (it's pid is 11570):

```
$ ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,command | grep 11570 |grep -v grep

11570 24322 11570 /bin/bash ./bash.sh
11577 11570 11570 /bin/bash ./bash.sh
11578 11570 11570 sleep 1000
11579 11577 11570 sleep 1001
```

then I'm killing it with ctrl+c and same ps returns:

```
11577     1 11570 /bin/bash ./bash.sh
11579 11577 11570 sleep 1001
```

Then:

```
kill -INT 11579
```

And nothing happnes (still same processes in bg)

I know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is same as killing it by:

```
kill -INT -11570
```

The same happens (same two processes are still in background).
Then - in next run - I killed processes within group one by one and found that the only one which cares is sleep which is not in function.

I thought then that main process finishes then and that's why it finishes. But then 'finish' should be printed. (as it is when I interrupt just this sleep)

**And now the questions are:**

**Why is only one sleep answering to interruption signal?**

How to make this script cleanup processes in backgound on interruption?

Comment: Sending the process to background detaches it from the current shell and runs on its own shell. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911387/2834978) shows how to kill it.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, as for killing this process I know how to kill it. (already answered). But how does this detachement explains not reacting for INT signal for one sleep, and reacting for other?

Comment: The INT signal is sent to current PID, not the background PID.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have killed them one by one. Let me stick with pid from example:
i did `kill -INT 11579` before `ctrl+c`

Comment: INT is ignored on background tasks as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106961).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is answer only for last question, but someone could use it.

To cleanup this trapping signal should work:

```
trap 'kill -TERM -$$' EXIT
```

On EXIT of script it is sending TERMINATE signal to its group (-$$). All processes with gpid same as main process pid will be terminated then.

PS.
I still don't know why only one sleep responds to INT signal and why it's happening.