# killing process group with SIGINT and SIGTERM shows different result

Tags: bash, kill, descendant

(I changed the point of question into about more basic symptom.)
I created child and grand child in bash script.(in Ubuntu 14.04)

```
#! /bin/bash

{
    sleep 21 &
    sleep 22
}&

sleep 23
```

But 2 kind of command to kill process group shows different result.
( I've run the kill command in another terminal at this test.)

```
kill -INT -<pgid>     # -> grand child(sleep 21) survives.
kill -TERM -<pgid>    # -> kills all correctly.
```

Could you explain what it is going on internally?

Comment: I see your latest edits are an attempt to resurrect this for reopening, but I don't think it's quite clear enough yet. I can probably edit it into shape and reopen it if you can clarify what you mean by "WCE policy". Quick googling gets me nothing even remotely promising.

Comment: I referred to [WCE](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) and [Ctrl+C](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/why-is-sigint-not-propagated-to-child-process-when-sent-to-its-parent-process)

Comment: I found the answer from googling. this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106725/why-do-shells-ignore-sigint-and-sigquit-in-backgrounded-processes) explains it well. thanks.