# Handling signals in bash script when it started as a background process

Tags: bash

Okay, I have a script like this:

```
trap 'echo "CTRL-C signal was caught!" ' SIGINT
for ((i=0; i<15; i++))
 do
   sleep 3
 done
```

When I start my script in a usual way, it immediately reacts to CTRL-C command and echo "CTRL-C signal was caught!", even if there is a sleep 3 command. But when I run my script as a background process, it waits until sleep 3 command is finished, and then echo "CTRL-C signal was caught!"
I do not understand this. I think trap should wait until previous command is finished, and then it should echo something, like when it started as a background process.

Comment: This is more a dupe of [Why do shells ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT in backgrounded processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45106725/5291015), but given the fact, the answer is not accepted, I'm keeping this open to get more answeers

Comment: This needs details and clarity, and a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) states:

- Background processes (...) are immune to keyboard-generated signals.
- If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be  executed  until the  command  completes.

Consequently:

- If your script runs in the foreground: when you press "Ctrl-C", a SIGINT is sent to the currently running process (i.e. the `sleep` command). The exit status of `sleep` tells Bash that it was interrupted by the SIGINT signal and `bash` calls your trap.
- If your script runs in the background, then the backgrounded `sleep` does not receive the signal and the SIGINT trap is only executed once `sleep` has ended.