# Docker Entrypoint script not taking any arguments in?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

Whilst developing my Dockerfile, I ran into an issue with the [Entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) instruction script; it's not taking my docker run arguments in.

Here is an example of what I tried, given:

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh  
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh  
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

With the following `entrypoint.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "I received:" "$@"
```

When I run the command:

```bash
docker run given/image:latest "A B C"
```

I expected the output:

```
I received: A B C
```

But instead, it was:

```
I received:
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the **shell** form of the ENTRYPOINT instruction. From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> The shell form:
>
> ```bash
> ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2
> ```
>
> The shell form *prevents* any CMD or run command line arguments from being used.

Whilst in practise it's possible to hack your way around this by amending your instruction to:

```
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh "$0" "$@"
```

However, I would recommend using the **exec** form as it passes Unix signals. (i.e. `SIGTERM`; `docker stop <container`)

Which is a simple syntax change:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The only inconvenience you run into when using the **exec** form is the fact that it will **not** do variable substitution so something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["$HOME/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Might not work as you would expect. Instead, you could do something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "$HOME/entrypoint.sh"]
```

(Do note that you will still run into the same [Unix signals problem if you wrapped your command with `sh -c`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106961/5037430). Thanks [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze))

For further details, see: [Dockerfile reference - exec form ENTRYPOINT example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example)

Comment: The initial string-only format is exactly equivalent to your final `["sh", "-c", ...]` option, and manually inserting the `sh -c` wrapper will bring back the same problems you're avoiding by changing to exec form.

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up, I was actually just about to test this on my machine (I was documenting this on SO as I go, I will amend the answer now).

Comment: One minor thing, shell form should be `ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh "$0" "$@"`

Comment: Just fixed, Thanks @Philippe .